# Pasting - copied union ranges into predefined columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping to get some help with a particular excel problem.

Copying from one workbook

```
Set x1 = .Range("D1:D" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)
Set x2 = .Range("F1:F" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)
Set x3 = .Range("G1:G" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)

Set xCopy = Union(x1, x2, x3)
```

The copy element works fine,

Problem:
I am keen to know if I can paste these ranges into specific columns in another workbook, using some type of paste union.

I know you can use the union to paste and specify the order. I am looking to specify order but in different columns.

x3 into column A, x2 into column C  and x1 into column F.

I am looking for the pasting code.

I look forward to getting some good ideas and thoughts, I often come here as I am a beginner in coding and I have checked the net and have not found a solution to my problem.  This gives me a chance to increase my knowledge.

Hi All, I have amended my union

```
Set xCopy = Union(x2, x3, x1)
```

Range("A2050").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

and it does not paste, in the order that I have selected, furthermore, I was trying to paste another selection below.

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I am getting an error, can anyone help, firstly why the union is not pasting in the order I have selected, secondly why I am getting an error with the offset.

Comment: AFAIK you *cannot* paste into a multi-area range. you'll need to copy/paste the columns one by one.

Comment: There must be another way of doing this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If you insist on using the union before the copy/paste, you can try to retrieve the areas... `For each area in xCopy.Areas  area.copy someDestination.` But that's ambiguous since the order and the number of those areas is not under your control.